# How to use a saved DynamoDBLocal.jar in dynamodb-local docker instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the Amazon local dynamodb docker image for local development: https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/ However, when it starts, it starts with an empty database.

I want to use a saved `./database/DynamoDBLocal.jar` in the container, however, I'm unsure and unable to use it.

in docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
image: "amazon/dynamodb-local"
ports:
    - "8000:8000"
volumes:
  - ./database:/database
```

I've tried to run the application command from inside the container:

```
$ docker-compose exec db /bin/sh
```

Then I attempt to run the java command:

```
/bin/java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar /database/DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -port 8887
```

And this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/AbstractHandler
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 19 more
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DynamoDBLocal.jar file is the java code that runs. You need to use the parameter `-dbPath` to specify the location of your database data.

For this particular docker image you should

```
  docker run -p 8000:8000 -v /host/directory/for/database:/database amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -dbPath /database
```

Comment: This is very informative. However, the real question I guess I'm asking is how do I pass the path to the database file to the container.